# how to implement sql server connection pooling in java jdbc?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection-pooling, mssql-jdbc

I tried to search for this but it seems the answer might now be true anymore. How can do connection pooling in java with sql server? I found the new jdbc driver of microsoft but there's no sample code to show to use it.

Comment: You should try [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [Apache DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). Both pages have examples of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft MSSQL-JDBC is now open sourced. You can see test cases used Hikari & Apache DBCP connection pool.

One can see [PoolingTest.java](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/connection/PoolingTest.java) and methods testApacheDBCP and testHikariCP.

For [HikariCP](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/connection/PoolingTest.java#L161) and [DBCP](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/connection/PoolingTest.java#L180)

Comment: @My Intek: I think you might able to configure connection pool.